# paypal IPN returns pending_reason: unilateral

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My PayPal IPN scripts runs very well. When I test with my sandbox account it, the payment is made instantly, however when I use my client's business email, I got `payment_status` as 'Pending', with `pending_reason` as 'unilateral' in the IPN log call.

My client's email is confirmed at PayPal. So can anyone tell me why I am getting this issue?

Answer (score 19):

`pending_reason=unilateral` means that the email address of the payment recipient has not been registered with PayPal. For the full list of pending reasons, see the [PayPal IPN documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id091EB04C0HS).

Check the email address for typos, and double-check with your client that they truly have registered their address with PayPal (they may not understand what this entails).

Comment: Yes Alex I have confirmed this thing from my client. They are registered with paypal and even they are recieving payments from their customers.

Comment: I'm really puzzled then Sarbjit. I recommend getting them to login to their PayPal account and confirming if they can see the payments. Also add a debug log line in your app to doublecheck that the email address you are sending is the same as their registered email.

Comment: I have already created a log file and email is same. Alex it may be the reason, if client has not confirmed his address (not email address) with paypal?

Comment: I don't think the real address matters. Get them to login and tell you if they can see the payments - and get them to send you a screenshot of their account details with email address. I suspect they've given you the wrong email. There aren't any weird characters in the email address are there?

Comment: ok I'll recheck with them again. Alex they are able to see the payments, because after the confirmation of payments they are placing the orders.

Comment: Alex my client shown me the payments that they recieved. I don't know whats going on, we call paypal for help let us see what will they respond. hope to get good news soon

Comment: I found that some times this happened while testing with sandbox account. Now I have tested it with live account, which is working fine now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 14):

Only accounts made in www.sandbox.paypal.com exists when testing on www.sandbox.paypal.com. So you can't use **live** accounts for testing, because they don't exist within the sandbox site. You should create the accounts at developer.paypal.com

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem - I was sending PayPal my "live" payer_email, when I changed it to the business email in the sandbox it worked. same as my live email with ****-facilitator@yoursite.com

Comment: I had the same problem here - for clarity's sake, in my case it was in the Paypal webhook I was sending the incorrect email, and switching this to ****-facilitator@yoursite.com got things working.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check if your Paypal primary email address has been confirmed. For me this error happened when my client's email wasn't confirmed yet, of all things!